# Importing a large delimited file to a MySQL table and adding new Identifiers

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to upload a large data set into MySQL.  The problem is it is all jumbled up and

Comment: It seems a pretty well formatted file, but outside of MySQLs capabilities to use directly. I'd write a short script in your favorite scripting language & use that to load it into MySQL.

Comment: thank you for your response, would you have any suggestions? I've never really parsed through huge data sets to create a more readable file for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

it's something like this:

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'nom_fichier'
INTO TABLE nom_table
[FIELDS
    [TERMINATED BY '\t']
    [ENCLOSED BY '']
    [ESCAPED BY '\\' ]
]
[LINES 
    [STARTING BY '']    
    [TERMINATED BY '\n']
]
```

For your example:

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'YourFile'
INTO TABLE TableName
[FIELDS
    [TERMINATED BY '\t']
    [ENCLOSED BY '']
    [ESCAPED BY '\\' ]//We don't need it here...
]
[LINES 
    [STARTING BY '']    
    [TERMINATED BY '\n']
]
```

Check it out here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was trying variations on this, but it wasn't working properly.  I've been looking at the website, I'm getting some syntax errors at the "[FIELDS" area.  Not sure what it could be.  Thank you :)